# $\underset{\bar{a},\bar{b}\in S^n}{Pr}[f(x,\bar{a}t+\bar{b})\text{ is reducible and }f(x,\bar{b})\text{ is square-free}]\leq\frac{7d^6}{|S|}$

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, hensels-lemma

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. Let $S\subset \mathbb{F}$ be a finite set
> with a size large enough. Let
> $f(x,y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)=f(x,\overline{y})$ be a almost monic and
> irreducible polynomial in total degree $d$ in $\mathbb{F}[x,\overline{y}]$. Then
> $$\underset{\overline{a},\overline{b}\in
> > S^n}{Pr}[f(x,\overline{a}t+\overline{b})\text{ is reducible and
> > }f(x,\overline{b})\text{ is square-free}]\leq \frac{7d^6}{|S|}$$

Here $S^n$ is the $n-$titmes cartesian product of $S$ and t is a variable. And almost monic means $\deg_x(f)=\deg(f(x,\overline{0})$

Honestly, I have zero idea how to prove this. I found a theorem very near to this: Hilbert Irreducibility Theorem that I can't prove.

The hint I got is that we have to Hensel Lift twice once with respect to modulo the ideal $(t)$ and once replacing the $\overline{a}$ with a formal variable $\overline{z}$ and then lift modulo the ideal $(\overline{z})$

Can you help me.